# Слушай меня(,) и слушай внимательно

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли здесь запятая: Слушай меня(,) и слушай внимательно

Answer (score 3):

***Слушай меня, и слушай внимательно.***

Я бы поставила запятую на том основании, что в данном предложении (при повторе слов) союз И можно считать **присоединительным**: *Слушай меня, причем слушай внимательно.* **Пауза** в устной речи присутствует.

В других случаях между сказуемыми, выраженными формой **повелительного** наклонения, **запятая не ставится** (они приравниваются к однородным членам):

Примеры:

― Пришло время щенят сажать на цепь. ***Слушай меня и молчи.*** [Алексей Иванов.  (1990-1991)]

***Слушай меня и не перебивай!*** [Эльдар Рязанов, Эмиль Брагинский. Старики-разбойники (1966-1969)]